# How to know it's the end of the line in c++ reading file

Tags: c++, readfile

I need to know how to stop if it's the end of the line

[image: this example of my file]

I need the int value for the last element which is 15
and also for the other lines, I need to know if this value is the last element in the line

i try getline(file ,line)
but it just gives me a string!
and also line.length(); gives me the length of the file.

Comment: That's exactly right.  Keep going.  Now that you have the line, parse out the last value in the line.

Comment: This is EOF, he's asking for end of line

Answer (score 2):

You should either use [std::getline](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) and parse the string you get, or go char-by-char and treat CR/LF as end of line. Then just move back from it until you get a space.

Answer (score 2):

You should continue to use your `getline` function, from that you will have your `std::string` then to pull your last digit use:

```
string str = <getline() result>
size_t last_index = str.find_last_not_of("0123456789");
string result = str.substr(last_index + 1);
int num = std::stoi(result);
```

This will give you your `int` representation of your last number.

Answer (score 1):

This will extract the last number on each line:

```
ifstream f ("./numbers");
vector<int> v;
int i;
while (f >> i) {
    char c = f.get();
    if (f.eof() || c == '\r' || c == '\n') {
        v.push_back(i);
    }    
}
```

`f.eof()` may be true if the file is not terminated by a new line, in which case the `f.get()` call may fail and set the eofbit.

Answer (score 0):

```
std::ifstream file{"your-file"};
std::string line;
while (getline(file, line)) {
    std::istringstream iss{line};
    std::vector<int> vec{std::istream_iterator<int>{iss},
                         std::istream_iterator<int>{}};
    if (vec.size() == 1) {
        // only one element
    }
    vec.back() // last value of the line (/!\ check not empty first)
}
```